# Invariance group of a polynomial equation?

Tags: group-theory

How to identify the invariance group of a polynomial equation under the replacement $x\to Tx$:

$$
x^2-2ax+a^2+b^2=0
$$

---

I am familiar with proving the invariance group of some type of linear transformations. For example, say I define the map $f$ as follows:

$$
f(x)=x^2
$$

I can identify the invariant group of the linear transformations on this map as follows. Let $T$ be a linear transformation, then:

$$
f(Tx)=(Tx)^2=T^2x^2=T^2f(x)
$$

Consequently, the group of linear transformations which leaves $f(x)$ invariant is the set of $T$ such that $T^2=1$.

---

Alternatively, $f(x)=x^2$ can be written as a polynomial

$$
x^2=a
$$

One can then ask that linear transformations leave $a$ invariant: the set of all $T$ such that $T^2x^2=a$.

And, for a more general polynomial, say

$$
x^2-2ax=a^2+b^2
$$

To find the invariance group, is it intuitively correct to ask for the set of all $T$ such that:

$$
(Tx)^2-2a(Tx)=a^2+b^2
$$

How would one then proceed to find the correct set of $T$?

---

edit: One can solve the term $(Tx)$ for its roots:

$$
Tx=\{a+ib, a-ib\}
$$

But I do not know how to interpret this... Does $T$ transform one root to the other? Does $T$ transform a complex number to its complex conjugation?